# How to create the following XML tag through DOM in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, domparser

```
<tableCategory>
        <item app_name="APPNAME1i" desc="BDESC1" lang="1ODDD"/>
</tableCategory>
```

In the above xml tag, I want to add one more item as follows-

```
<item app_name="APPNAME2" desc="DESC2" lang="2ODDD"/>
```

So finally the XML tag will look like-

```
<tableCategory>
            <item app_name="APPNAME1i" desc="BDESC1" lang="1ODDD"/>
                <item app_name="APPNAME2" desc="DESC2" lang="2ODDD"/>
 </tableCategory>
```

I am getting the tag -

```
Element paletteElement = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("tableCategory").item(0); //tag
```

But not getting the clue after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using `javax.xml.parsers`, `element.appendChild()` will do.

**[edited]**

In case, you are looking for how to create a new `Element`, below is an example snippet

```
Element newElem = doc.createElement("item");
newElem.setAttribute(...);
...
...
elem.addChild(newElem);
```

Comment: One question, as I am keep on adding/write the tag inside xml file, how to provide next line scenario for the same..

Comment: @Abhishek: Most XML parser doesn't care about `next-line` character, everything is good as far as the document is well-formed. So, precisely just keep on `addChild()` without worrying about that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Element.addContent()](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/Element.html#addContent%28org.jdom.Content%29) method

Comment: are you talking about Element.appendChild ?

Comment: I don't think he is using `jdom`.